# Change options view in tabpane javafx when opening the application

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I created a TabPane that has 4 tabs in it and each tab has buttons in it. Every time I run my application, at the first run it always shows like I already pressed on the 'Maintain Questions' tab which is of course not true [Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb9dw.jpg). How can I change it that it will show me nothing from the tabs when I open the application?
I did it with the scene builder so here is my fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="861.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TeacherWindowController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="669.0" fitWidth="985.0" focusTraversable="true" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../bigstock-Stack-Of-Books-70033240.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Text fx:id="welcomeText" fill="WHITE" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="40.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome" wrappingWidth="370.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font></Text>
      <Text fx:id="TextGroup7" layoutX="365.0" layoutY="664.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Copyright © 2018 Group7" />
      <ImageView fx:id="Group7Logo" blendMode="MULTIPLY" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="348.0" layoutY="572.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../logo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Text fx:id="date" fill="#fffdfd" layoutX="831.0" layoutY="39.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" wrappingWidth="140.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="addQuestiton" layoutX="298.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Add Question" visible="false" />
      <Button fx:id="editOrRemoveQuestion" layoutX="298.0" layoutY="116.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Edit/Remove Question" visible="false" />
      <Button fx:id="logoutButton" layoutX="910.0" layoutY="52.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logOutButtonHandler" text="Logout" />
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="44.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="145.0" prefWidth="533.0" style="-fx-focus-traversable: false;" styleClass="TeacherWindow.css" stylesheets="@TeacherWindow.css" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Maintain Questions">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="146.0" stylesheets="">
                     <children>
                        <Button focusTraversable="false" layoutX="-10.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Edit/Remove Question" />
                        <Button focusTraversable="false" layoutX="-10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="173.0" text="Add Question" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Maintain Exams">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane focusTraversable="false" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="Order Reports">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Confirm Grades">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="763.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible without a lot of 'hacky workarounds'. Though from the Picture it seems like you use it as a `Menu`? So why don't you try the `MenuBar` instead of a `TabPane`?

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/menubar.html) on MenuBars which might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks!!! Do you know where I can find tutorial about the MenuBar in scene builder?

Comment: The `MenuBar` can be found under the 'Containers' section (on the left-hand side). All the different menu(item)s can be found under the `Menu` section. Since you have already worked with SceneBuilder I guese the rest speaks for itself?